# How mix up a word ? C++

Tags: c++

I just can't mix up my word, it's getting me anything I don't want.
I have no errors, no warnings but Whe I put a string I have std::out_of_range

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

string melangeLettre(string mot);
int main()
{
    cout << "Saisissez un mot mystere: \n> ";
    string motMystere{};
    cin >> motMystere;

    cout << "Quel est ce mot ?\n";
    string const newMot{melangeLettre(motMystere)};
    cout << newMot << endl;

    return {0};
}

string melangeLettre(string mot)
{
    size_t random = chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    mt19937 gen{random};
    string newMot{};

    for (unsigned int i{}; i < mot.size(); ++i)
    {
        uniform_int_distribution<> getNbr(0, mot.size());
        int const alea{mot[getNbr(gen)]};

        newMot.push_back(alea);
        mot.erase(alea, 1);
    }

    return newMot;
}
```

The problem is on ' melangeLettre ' function, please someone can help me to resolve this ?

Comment: If you want to scramble a string you should use [`std::random_suffle()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)

Comment: Yes in algorithm include, but I don't want use a ready function.

Comment: So what results *are* you getting, if not errors or warnings? Are the strings not shuffled? Do they return empty, or duplicated?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Shuffling a string](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDIQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F8364597%2Fshuffling-string&ei=_WpKVaLCLdTjoASQvIHgBQ&usg=AFQjCNGD5pNHfNO63AqbkL9YF32vPhcQqQ&sig2=B_f1ro0MJshc9E5OabbBEg&bvm=bv.92291466,d.cGU)

Comment: When I put a string I have :  std::out_of_range

Comment: I think you are using the character value of your random letter as the index for the character you want to erase. I think you need to keep a note of your random position `getNbr(gen)` and use *that* as the character to `erase()`.

Comment: maybe it should be `uniform_int_distribution<> getNbr(0, mot.size()-1);` ?

Comment: Also your `for()` loop won't work because the size of your word `mot` keeps changing.

Comment: @galik is right it should be `while(mot.size())`

Comment: Why all the down votes? OP made a genuine effort and has provided his code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the character value of your random letter as the index for the character you want to erase. I think you need to keep a note of your random position `getNbr(gen)` and use that as the character to `erase()`.

Also your `for()` loop won't work because the size of your word `mot` keeps changing.

Finally your integer distribution is an *inclusive* range.

This is with the above corrections:

```
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream> // need this

using namespace std;

string melangeLettre(string mot);
int main()
{
    cout << "Saisissez un mot mystere: \n> ";
    string motMystere{};
    cin >> motMystere;

    cout << "Quel est ce mot ?\n";
    string const newMot{melangeLettre(motMystere)};
    cout << newMot << endl;

    return {0};
}

string melangeLettre(string mot)
{
    size_t random = chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    mt19937 gen{random};
    string newMot;

//    for (unsigned int i{}; i < mot.size(); ++i)
    while(!mot.empty()) // mot keeps changing size so use this
    {
//        uniform_int_distribution<> getNbr(0, mot.size());
        uniform_int_distribution<> getNbr(0, mot.size() - 1); // range inclusive!

        auto pos {getNbr(gen)}; // store the position of the letter
        auto alea {mot[pos]};

        newMot.push_back(alea);
        mot.erase(pos, 1); // erase the letter from the stored position
    }

    return newMot;
}
```

Comment: Oh yes the problem was the for loop !
Thank's you so much :)